# How to use the "Get files"-action from Azure Logic App for more than 100 files?

Tags: sharepoint-online, azure-logic-apps

I am trying to catch all files from a folder of a SharePoint document library. And it always only gets me the first 100 files. I found the limit [setting for a Flow](https://natechamberlain.com/2017/11/11/how-to-change-microsoft-flows-default-limit-of-100-items-for-get-items-and-get-rows-actions/) (or new Microsoft Power Automate) but not for a Logic App.
[image]
I could not find any paging or limit parameter in the settings of the "Get files"-action.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

There is a parameter controlling how man entries should be returned "Top Count". And it says the default is returning all entries. What seems not to be true, because it does not.
[image: Not-working-default]
As a workaround, I was able to set a number higher than 100 and get more files. So, I can postpone the bug.
[image: workaround]

Comment: Sadly it stops now at 1006 files, if I put 2000 as Top Count. Any ideas? The action runs for 2 min. I already set the timeout in the action to PT30M, what should result in 30 minutes.

Comment: Does the used API connection object that connects to to SharePoint during the "Get files" action has a time restriction? I could not find such a configuration option on the API connection configuration page.